# snmpwalk: Supressing the "Wrong Type (should be xxx)" when loading a custom mib

Tags: unix, snmp

I'm using some custom mibs but for some items I get a message like:

```
$ snmpwalk -c enterprise -v 1 -M mib -m ALL host iso.3.6.1.4.1.5485.2.10.111.1.1
...
MYCOMPANY-MIB::rejectedMessages.11 = Wrong Type (should be Counter32): INTEGER: 0
..
```

I know there is a mismatch between the mib file and the snmp data, but I want just to supress the warning. Changing the mib isn't an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about just piping it through `grep -vi 'Wrong Type'` ?

Comment: I need to suppress the message, not the entire line.

Comment: filter it through `| sed -e 's/Wrong Type (should be .*)://'` ?

Comment: Ok, I'll accept this workaround =)